# Parse User Auto Login

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I'm trying to get my app to segue directly to the Profile Page after start is a PFUser is already logged in that way they won't have to keep logging in unless the completely stop the app.  It's not working.  Maybe I'm not checking for PFUser nil correctly.  Please help. Here's what I'm putting in viewDidLoad.....

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if PFUser.currentUser()?.username != nil
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToProfileSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: try `if PFUser.currentUser() != nil...`

Comment: That didn't work.  I've done this before and it worked.  Do you think the PFUser should be saved in some way???

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything.  Have you set a breakpoint to check what is happening?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I had something funky in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  It kept my initial view did Load stuff from loading.  I didn't realize that would be a consequence.